# SQL Query in Entitymanger.createNativeQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am a newbie to the hibernate JPA.

Can i Use SQL query directly in to an `Entitymanger.createNativeQuery.createNativeQuery` like following

```
 Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
                            "select * from dbo.TGEO_PARM_VALUE where PARM_DEF_UID= (select PARM_DEF_UID from dbo.TGEO_PARM_DEF where PARM_KEY_NM='VRSN_CHG_MOD_CD')");
```

or else i have to use the entities which mapped to the tables instead of direct table names in the query.

And also please guide me how to retrieve the data from  `q.getResultList()`.

Comment: Use native queries only when they are absolutely needed (use them when for example, you need some underlying database function which is not natively supported by an ORM). Otherwise, there is no meaning to use an ORM, if everything done using native queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native SQL like that, and to map the results you can simply create a class (if you already don't have one) with fields that match the returned columns (the ones you specify in `SELECT` clause), and pass it in `createNativeQuery` call

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from dbo.TGEO_PARM_VALUE where PARM_DEF_UID= (select PARM_DEF_UID from dbo.TGEO_PARM_DEF where PARM_KEY_NM='VRSN_CHG_MOD_CD')", MyClass.class);
```